# Best way to dynamically change element's color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Which method is more efficient to change the color of an object?
for the example i'll use a  element

1) adding the element a class with jQuery when it's loaded (removing other colors that might be there already)

```js
var element = $('div');
element.removeClass("red");
element.removeClass("blue");
element.removeClass("green");

var newColor = "red green or blue";
element.addClass(newColor);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

2) adding a field of the color and using css selector to check it

```css
div[data-color=green] {
  background-color: green;
  }

div[data-color=red] {
  background-color: red;
  }

div[data-color=green] {
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div data-color="green"></div>
```

Which is better?
Is there a better method that I didn't mention?
Thank you!

Comment: Even though this is too broad question, I would like to suggest second method to use as its not required overload on DOM

Comment: From a seperation of concerns point of view, stylings should be changed by changing the class names of an element. Do note that freshly created elements don't have a class yet, so no need to remove the 3 colors from a freshly created div. Also, you can set the className to an empty string to remove all classes from an element at the same time. Data attributes for styling just looks weird, since you're basically just recreating what class is supposed to do. And inline styles should always be a last resort, like for emails. (due to seperation of concerns, easier future restylings, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are fairly the same, however, the first option I have in mind is not messing with custom attributes or classes, but directly changing the inline style:

```
var el = $('el')
el.css('background-color', '#FF0000')
```